# Height dinâmico em 'carrinho de produtos'

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu tenho uma `div` que serve como um carrinho de produtos, ela fica fixa no topo da tela onde só aparece o `subtotal` de todos os produtos escolhidos e ao clicar sobre a `div`, ela faz um efeito de slide para baixo e mostra todos os produtos.

Eu fiz o efeito do `slide` com animação no `css`, e eu deixo a `div` fixa no topo com Top negativo, de acordo com o tamanho da div, por exemplo, `top: -370px`.

O problema é que o tamanho da `div` é dinâmico, aumenta conforme vai sendo adicionados produtos,  então mesmo com o top negativo, a div não 'esconde' todos os produtos. Já tentei ir mudando a propriedade top conforme os botões de adicionar produto são clicados, o que dá certo, porém não sei como mudar o top da animação que faz descer e subir a div.

Alguém sabe se tem como mudar essa propriedade ou se há uma forma melhor de fazer esse efeito?

Pra ficar mais fácil o entendimento: https://jsfiddle.net/84rczeds/2/

Comment: Dá pra simplificar bastante seu carrinho amigo.

Comment: Então estou querendo deixar as animações só em css, mas acho que acabei complicando demais mesmo haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não entendi muito bem o que quis dizer, mas acho que é isso que você quer.

```js
var subtotal = $('.subtotal').height();

$('.subtotal-menu').click(function(event) {
    $('.subtotal').addClass('slideDown').removeClass('slideUp');
    $('.subtotal-menu').hide();
    $('.close-subtotal').show();
});

$('.close-subtotal').click(function(event) {
    $('.subtotal').addClass('slideUp').removeClass('slideDown');
    $('.subtotal-menu').show();
    $('.close-subtotal').hide();
});

$('button').click(function() {
   $('.produtos').append('<p>Produto X</p><hr>');
      subtotal = $('.subtotal').height();
      $('.subtotal').css('top', '-'+subtotal+'px')
      alert(subtotal)
});
```

```css
.subtotal {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  top: -170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

@keyframes slideDown {
  
  to {
    top: 0;
  }
}

.slideDown {
    animation-name: slideDown;
    animation-duration: .5s;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
}

@keyframes slideUp {
  from {
    top: 0;
  }
  
}

.slideUp {
    animation-name: slideUp;
    animation-duration: .5s;
    nimation-fill-mode: both;
}
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-k2WSCIexGzOj3Euiig+TlR8gA0EmPjuc79OEeY5L45g="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="subtotal">
  <div class="produtos">
    <p>Produto 1</p>
    <hr>
    <p>Produto 2</p>
    <hr>
    <p>Produto 3</p>
  </div>
    <hr>
    <p>Subtotal: x</p>
  
 
</div>
 <span class="subtotal-menu" style="cursor: pointer;">O</span>
 <span class="close-subtotal" style="display: none; cursor: pointer;">X</span>
 
 <button>add Produto</button>
```

Comment: Sim, é mais ou menos isso que eu quero mesmo. Conforme vai adicionando produtos, a div continue mostrando só a parte onde tem o subtotal. Tem alguma foma de mexer na propriedade da animação também? Porque clicando com o botão e adicionando produtos, a div permanece onde tem que estar, mas quando faz a animação pra div voltar ela continua com o top de antes.

Comment: Você não precisa dos 'from' e 'to' dos Keyframes, se você tirar a animação vai funcionar perfeitamente, atualizei na minha resposta, vê se é o que precisa.

Comment: Ficou exatamente do jeito que eu queria! Realmente não tinha me tocado de que não precisara do 'from' e 'to' pra fazer a animação. Obrigado mesmo!

Comment: @FelipeEvangelista De nada, não esquece de deixar +1 abraços

Answer (score 1):

Não seria melhor você repensar sua lógica pra ficar mais fácil?
Assim o código ta fazendo muito calculo desnecessário, veja um exemplo:

Crie uma `div` para englobar os produtos e o subtotal e nela adicione o css pra ficar no topo, a estrutura `html` vai ficar assim:

```
<div class="engloba-tudo">

   <div class="produtos">
     // Sua lista de produtos
   </div>
   <div class="subtotal ">
     // Subtotal dos produtos
   </div>

</div>
```

Agora basta voce deixar sua `div` produtos com `display:none;` e como vi que está usando `Jquery` pode usar a função `slideToggle()` que já economiza bastante código pra fazer mostrar os produtos:

```
$(".subtotal").click(function() {
   $(".produtos").slideToggle(300);
})
```

Exemplo no [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8j1fug31/2/).
Mas é só uma idéia, pois como também ja fiz um carrinho com animação sei como é chato pra dar manutenção ou alterar código grande, além de ter maior chance de travamentos;

Comment: Ficou mais simples mesmo, estou tentando usar mais animação com o css, mas acho que acabei complicando demais as coisas haha